# Pretty .Net GUI Library Like using in Yahoo Messenger

Tags: .net, user-interface, controls

Please, advise me any .net gui controls library for create user interface like in Yahoo messenger or like Trillian. May be this will be easy skin-based interface library or other. I need only simple controls ex. buttons, listview combobox, checkbox and other therefore library must be small. I know DevExpress and Infragistics libraries but they are too big.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use WPF? You can customize yourself to death. Go for [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) if you wants to do a lot of customization.